# Installing Ubuntu on Surface 3

Tags: system-installation, 15.04, surface

Everything I've found web about the Microsoft Surface 3 and Ubuntu concern the Surface Pro 3 with a Core-I processor. Does anyone have anything to share about installing Ubuntu on the Surface 3 (*not* Pro) with the Atom x7 proccessor?

Comment: Did you end up installing Ubuntu?  I'm curious as well and can't find any positive reports.

Comment: Sorry it took so long.  I ended up returning this item and buying an HP Stream 13 instead.  Got Ubuntu on it just fine.  It even handled the touch screen well.